# bxslider seamless loop with set amount of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I want the image slider to always show 3 images and scroll 3 images at a time.
So far everything works just fine as long as I always have a set of 3 images for each slide. 
The problem is that when I for instance try to use a total of 7 images to my image slider, the slider just scrolls 1 image at the end instead of 3, before it starts over as usual scrolling 3 at the time.

Is there any way to make the image slider scroll in a seamless way, meaning that after the last slide (image7, image1, image2), the next slide would continue as image3, image4, image5?
Now it just resets itself to 1,2,3 after the last slide.

Comment: Can you add your code please? Or better yet, head over to jsbin.com and create a working example so others can play with the code.

Comment: can you create js fiddle for your problem